# Syntax Error: Unexpected token return -- I can't use 'return' in switch case?

Tags: javascript, return, syntax-error

I was testing out my function by calling it like this:
`determineWinner ('rock', 'rock');`

But I got this error message:

```
computerChoice === 'paper' ? return "Computer wins!" : return "User wins!";
                                   ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

Here is the function:

```
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  };
  switch (userChoice) {
    case 'rock':
      computerChoice === 'paper' ? return "Computer wins!" : return "User wins!";
      break;
    case 'paper':
      computerChoice === 'scissors' ? return "Computer wins!" : return "User wins!"
      break;
    case 'scissors':
      computerChoice === 'rock' ? return "Computer wins!" : return "User wins!"
      break;
  };
};

determineWinner ('rock', 'rock');
```

I know that you aren't meant to use 'return' outside of functions but I don't think I did? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Correct syntax is `a = condition ? b : c;`, not `a = condition ? return b: return c;`, which means you should write it as `return computerChoice === 'paper' ? "Computer wins!" : "User wins!";`

Answer (score 0):

You Can't return from the ternary operator. the ternary operator already returns without using the keyword explicitly. Instead, try to catch that returned value in some mutable variable. In your case, you can do like this:-

```
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return "It's a tie!";
  };
  let whoWins = '';
  switch (userChoice) {
    case 'rock':
      whoWins = computerChoice === 'paper' ?  "Computer wins!" :  "User wins!";
      break;
    case 'paper':
      whoWins=computerChoice === 'scissors' ?  "Computer wins!" :  "User wins!"
      break;
    case 'scissors':
     whoWins= computerChoice === 'rock' ?  "Computer wins!" :  "User wins!"
      break;
      default:
     whoWins=  'No one wins';
  };
 return whoWins
};

console.log(determineWinner ('rock', 'rock'));
```

**This will going to work absolutely fine**

Comment: Your reason is correct, but there's no need for the extra mutable variable and the extra assignment. It could be `return a === b ? 'foo' : 'bar'`